# Record sound from audio mixer using C & Windows

Tags: c, windows, audio, record

I'd like to record the sound playing on the computer (not just the mike!), just like Audacity does.
To do that, it appears that I need to record the sound of the audio mixer (audio mapper).

I'd like to know how to do that using the **langage C**, on Windows.

Thanks!
Have a nice day!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to get the code written for you. Narrow your question down to something like "How to capture audio going to the system output on Windows". If you need a large amount of code written for you, look into contract programming.

Comment: You're right, the question was suspicious, I have rephrased it ;p

Comment: Very good. I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: i think its best to use a library and not the win api.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at **[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/)** - here are [Tutorial](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html) and [Api Documentation](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/). It's used by [audacity too](http://portaudio.com/apps.html)!

some features:

- cross-platform
- open source
- simple
- C and C++

Possible the Win Api provides what you need, check out [Waveform Audio Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms925320.aspx).